# установка русской локали при чтении файла

Tags: c++, locale

Был такой вот код

```
std::wifstream dict_file{dictionary_file_name};
//....
dict_file.imbue(std::locale("ru_RU.UTF-8"));
std::wstring word;
while (dict_file >> word)
  dictionary.insert(word);
```

и он долгое время работал , изначально писался под Win8.1

при попытке запустить (оригинального exe нет, пришлось собрать заново MSVC2015x64) падает по исключению на конструкторе локали с ошибкой bad locale name

в чем может быть дело? 
посмотрел например [сюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzz3tw78.aspx) 
вообще получается должно быть не ru_RU а ru-RU? 
вообщем у кого есть опыт - поделитесь пожалуйста

Comment: А зачем вам _русская_ локаль при чтении файла? Если файл в utf-8, русский язык тут не при чём.

Comment: файл действительно в UTF-8 почему ставится русская локаль за давностью уже не помню но без нее читаются в строку бракозябры

Comment: Вам нужно именно чтение utf-8. Не бывает такого понятия, как «русская utf-8», поэтому сама запись «`ru_RU.UTF-8`» кажется мне бессмысленной, если честно. (Может, линуксоиды объяснят.)

Comment: согласен :) буду разбираться. спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня работает так:

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <fstream>

// ...
std::locale utf8_to_utf16(std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>);
std::wifstream dict_file{your_path_here};
dict_file.imbue(utf8_to_utf16);
std::wstring word;
while (dict_file >> word)
{
    // ...
}
```

(Visual Studio 2015.)

При этом в тексте могут быть, разумеется, одновременно символы любых языков, не только кириллица.

Comment: спасибо! тоже пришел к такому к такому решению но видимо на 10 минут позднее :)

Comment: @amigo421: Пожалуйста! Если двое пришли к такому решению, значит, должно быть правильно.